# What kind of test in R should I run to compare a factor to a number, and then factor to factor?

Tags: r, chi-squared, t-test

I have a factor of values, "Good" and "Bad" in the first column for both dataframes listed below:

- I have one dataframe that contains columns of 20 different numerics.
- I have a second dataframe that contains columns of 9 different factors.

What I would like to do is a type of test to be able to say which numerics and factors (within 95% confidence) accurately predict whether a factor is "Good" or "Bad" in the dataframes listed above.

I started by figuring out how to use lapply to create a function to compare the first column to the numerics as so:

```
tests <- lapply(1:22, function(x) t.test(df[,x] ~ df[,23]))
```

This runs but most p-values are:

> p-value < 2.2e-16

So I feel like I'm doing something wrong here.

As far as the second where I'm comparing two factors to each other I'm a little lost.  I got some advice to use the chisq.test in order to compare them such as:

```
chisq.test(statusGoodBad, state)
```

However, that also has a low p-value such as:

> p-value = 7.462e-16

and also gives the warning:

> Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

Comment: Nothing wrong with getting a tiny p-value. 2.2e-16 is just essentially 0. Your columns are most likely very different. The warning about Chi-squared being incorrect is probably because you have cells with low counts. Check `table(statusGoodBad, state)` - it may not be a big issue however.

Comment: I thought the null hypothesis was that the two values were different- so anything over 0.05 (95% confidence) I’d say where too different, and anything under p=0.05 for a 95% confidence meant they were similar. Do I have it flipped around?

Comment: It's possible to check your question. Compare the results when the means are roughly the same - `t.test(rnorm(1000,mean=10,sd=1), rnorm(1000,mean=10,sd=1))` vs clearly different `t.test(rnorm(1000,mean=10,sd=1), rnorm(1000,mean=20,sd=1))`

Comment: The t.test with two random samplings of n=1000 and a mean of 10 and sd of 1 had the higher p-value.  So my inference is that the null hypothesis is that the true difference in means is equal to 0- so the ones with higher the p-value the likelier that the numbers are the related.